# Open site in new tab of existing Chrome instance when debugging

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2017

When debugging a web application in Visual Studio is it possible to get it to launch in an existing tab of an existing instance of Chrome rather than in a new window when clicking the Launch in Chrome button [image: launch in Chrome]?

Comment: I've discovered that disabling javascript debugging in Visual Studio's options enables the site to open in an existing Chrome instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance

Answer (score 158):

On the Menu bar of Visual Studio, go to

> *Tools > Options*

After that, a window will pop up.

From there, navigate to

> *Debugging > General* > **uncheck** *Enable Javascript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)*

[image: launch in Chrome]

**Since Visual Studio 15.7.0**

You also need to uncheck option:

> *Tools > Options > Projects And Solutions > Web Projects > Stop debugger when browser window is closed*