# Prevent Visual Studio 2022 from opening a new browser, but instead open in a new tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Before you go crazy: Yes, this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716494/stop-visual-studio-from-launching-a-new-browser-window-when-starting-debug), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933775/vs-used-to-open-browser-in-new-tab-now-opens-new-browser), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673989/open-site-in-new-tab-of-existing-chrome-instance-when-debugging). Probably a lot more, but these were the first results when searching.

I'm running VS 2022 Preview 5.0, I've created a Blazor WASM project, and I've tried every single suggestion I could find to stop VS from opening a new browser but instead open in a tab. I'm also running Windows 11, which might cause some weird issues with "default apps", but I did check and all my .html, HTTP, HTTPS, etc. links are set to open in Google Chrome.

Here is a video showing that I already have Chrome open, I have disabled `Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops` and `Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)`: https://i.imgur.com/azLDram.mp4

I also tried enabling both, saving, disabling them again, and then saving.

Did Microsoft introduce a new 3rd thing that might cause this to happen, or am I just running a bugged version of Visual Studio?

EDIT: I just completely removed VS 2022 Preview 5.0 and installed VS 2022 17.0.5 (not Preview), and the problem still occurs.

EDIT 2: When I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> it opens a new tab in my existing Chrome window (as expected), but I want debugging at some point. This is so weird.

EDIT 3:

I found a possible solution, but there is a downside to it.

`launchSettings.json` has an `inspectUri`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57110",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove that `inspectUri` property, it will open a new tab instead of a window. However, none of my debug symbols are loaded, which means I can't set a breakpoint and debug the code. The symbols are loaded if I keep the `launchUri` and I use the Chrome window instead.

If I then keep the window open, but I open the URL in my regular Chrome window, I still cannot debug. Debugging only works if I use the window Visual Studio opens for me. I guess this is intentional for Blazor WASM projects, but it is really annoying.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-always-opens-new-browser-and-st/1606229

Answer (score 16):

turning off this setting worked for me

[image]