# Visual Studio 2022 - Chrome debug window is opened on top of existing Chrome window

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022, taskbar

When I launch my ASP.NET Core Web Api project in VS Pro the resulting Swagger page is opened in a new browser places on top of an existing Chrome Browser window. This is driving me crazy!
Opening the same project in VS Community Edition opens the Windows where I last closed it. It remembers the setting and it creates a new taskbar icon for the window.

How can I make VS Pro behave the same as Community Edition?

Comment: Do these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673989/open-site-in-new-tab-of-existing-chrome-instance-when-debugging  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance

Comment: No. Looked at those as I rote this thread. Its weird that Community and Pro have different settings!

Comment: @TimothyG. I stand corrected. This is indeed the option I was looking for it seems. Flopping the option in the screenshot below also changes the value of Tools/Options/Debugging 'Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET'.

Comment: The question was not focused. One of the other commenters found it confusing. Also I found a solution. Or rather it turns out that the controller was already being loaded automatically. I just hadn't noticed! Then I found some code by which I could prevent controllers from being loaded.
I appreciate your help. Sorry I deleted it but it suddenly looked like a stupid thread now that I figured out the LogController service was already loaded... DUH!

Answer (score 1):

Script Debugging setting is the culprit. If disabled Chrome will launch on top of existing Chrome windows. If enabled it will start a new Chrome windows where it was last closed.

[image]

Comment: I put a breakpoint in a line of javasciprt code. Since I was working on multiple projects, it was very annoying to open 4 new Chrome windows every time. Thanks for the answer and question.