# Visual Studio 2017 starts new instance of browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and it starts new instance of browser for web applications. I want to start it in the current opened browser, without any new instances (which closes when I stop debugging). Where is this setting?

Comment: Try turning off Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of a new feature in VS 2017 that allows javascript running in Chrome, to be debugged inside Visual Studio.  You can turn the feature off from

> Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET

[image]

The reason this feature requires a new instance of Chrome, is that the debugger connection requires Chrome to be launched with a specific command-line switch that can only be applied at process start, not to currently running processes.

The feature is explained in detail [click here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/).

One other interesting note, is that opening Chrome's developer console, with F12, will have the side-effect of detaching Visual Studio's debugger from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this easily.

Go to "*Tools*" > "*Options*" > "*Projects and Solutions*" > "*Web Projects*"
Uncheck the item "*Stop debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stop*s" > "*Ok*"

This should do the needful for you.