# In VS 2017(15.7.0) on debug web project starts new instance of browser insted of open new tab in existing

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017

Even when i make recommendations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464540/visual-studio-2017-starts-new-instance-of-browser). 
[Screen of Debug options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryzHB.png)

How should i configure VS to open new tab in existing instance on default browser?

P.S. VS 2017 version 15.7.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's really annoying. I tried

`Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and turn off the setting Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).`

but it's no use. I'm using VS 2017 Community Edition 15.7.1

Comment: Same problem with VS 2017 15.7.1...Even if i drag and drop manually tab opened by VS to my main chrome instance it stop the debugging session...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I found for the moment is to uncheck the `"Stop debugger when the browser window is closed"` in

> Visual Studio > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects

Comment: however, in future visual studio updates try to see if this works normally by checking the box again. I do not know the side effects of unchecking the box (perhaps CPU load etc)