# How can I start a new Chrome instance in Visual Studio on website startup without Javascript Debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2017

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance/42674555), you can start an empty Chrome on by enabling Javascript debugging, but I don't want to enable Javascript Debugging!!! It's causing some weird errors with ServiceWorkers, and Chrome's Debugger is way better anyway. how can I start en empty chrome instance without Javascript debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top right of the chrome browser, you can add a new User, new users don't have any extensions. I've added an new user called "Developer", and use that for testing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution with us, please mark it as answer which could help more people.