# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 v15.7.2 opening debugging session in a new browser window?

Tags: visual-studio

Since installing Visual Studio update v15.7.2, clicking "Start Debugging" in a .Net project now opens a new browser window instead of adding a tab to my existing browser window, as it had done previously. How do I get this to stop and go back to adding a new tab to my existing browser window?

In my scenario; I have an existing browser window open (Google Chrome, my preferred development browser) and I click Debug > Start Debugging. Result: It opens a new Chrome window. Preferred Result: It adds a new tab to my existing browser window.

Note: This is not related to the option for "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome, Edge and IE)" as previous posts point to separately - as this option is already disabled for me. I'm assuming there is another toggle somewhere that I don't know about and need to change.

Any help/pointers much appreciated.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Comment: @EricHerlitz That link is for a similar but different problem that occurs when upgrading to VS2017. As pointed out in the original post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Do not open new browser instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095299/visual-studio-do-not-open-new-browser-instance)

Comment: @EricHerlitz thanks but that is not the issue I am having, which I stated in the question it's something different.

Comment: @TomGlenn 's answer below worked for me, thanks. I will accept this as the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue since upgrading to 15.7.1+
The solution is a bit obscure and hidden in the Tools -> Options menu.

To revert to the previous functionality, where it opens a new debug session in an already open browser window with a new tab, do the following:

**Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Untick Stop debugger when browser window is closed**

Reference:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/247841/web-debug-always-opens-new-browser-window-and-clos.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to list where you choose the browse with options(IIS Express,Web Browser,Browse with etc.),there is an option script debugging, disable it and you are done.

[image: Here is the pic]

Comment: Thanks but this is not the problem I am having as I stated in the question - it is already disabled. Appreciate your help. Tomglenn's answer above worked for me.